# Forward all data sent to XXX to BBB

Tags: ip, forwarding, packet

I want to forward all that that is being sent to IP XXX and send it to IP BBB

Example:
A packet is being sent to IP 23.24.165.56, I want that packet to be sent to IP 127.0.0.1 instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wheres the packet coming from and wheres it going? Does it pass though a router? Your saying you want the packet sent back to yourself right?

Comment: Operating System? Router? Firewall? Any configuration details at all?!

Comment: Its on local computer. Well software is connecting to IP XXX and is communicating with that IP. I need it connect to other IP 127.0.0.1

Comment: Computer One can't see Computer Two's 127.0.0.1. Computer One sends to Computer Two's IP address, 192.168.0.1 for example. Once computer Two has got it, what's the point? Or do you not really mean "127.0.0.1"?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261807/is-it-possible-to-forward-all-traffic-to-an-ip-address may be able to help you out, depending on your particular requirements.